# clearInterval inside callback in ClojureScript

Tags: clojure, setinterval, clojurescript, clearinterval

Basically, what I want is to implement this piece of code in ClojureScript:

```
var win = window.open('foo.html', 'windowName');   
var timer = setInterval(function() {   
    if(win.closed) {  
        clearInterval(timer);  
        alert('closed');  
    }  
}, 1000);
```

I tried this:

```
(let [popup (.open js/window "foo.html" "windowName")
      interval (.setInterval
                js/window
                (fn []
                  (when (.-closed popup)
                    (do
                      ;; 'interval' is undefined at this point
                      (.clearInterval js/window interval)

                      (.alert js/window 'closed')))
                1000)]
...)
```

but CLJS compiler gives me a warning that `interval` is not defined.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you copy-pasted your code? There are typos in your code (`inteval` -> `interval`, `clearInteval` -> `clearInterval`)

Comment: sorry for this. anyway problem persists even if typos are fixed

Comment: To me, recursively calling setTimeout is often a better fit with functional programming. I'd definitely use setTimeout in the JavaScript version as well in this case. (I guess that doesn't really answer the question so I left it as a comment only.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you access `interval` local binding in your anonymous function before that binding has been defined (right hand side has to be evaluated first before it gets bound to `interval` symbol and until then `interval` is not defined.

You might workaround it by defining an atom storing your interval and access it from your callback function:

```
(let [popup (.open js/window 'foo.html', 'windowName')
      interval (atom nil)]
  (reset! interval (.setInterval
                    js/window
                    (fn []
                      (when (.-closed popup)
                        (do
                          (.clearInterval js/window @interval)
                          (.alert js/window "Closed")))))))
```

I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to achieve it using your approach with an interval callback.

Answer (score 4):

Use of an `atom`

- is *easy*
- and is included within ClojureScript's core functionality

however `interval` *being* an `atom` may not clearly convey its actual nature and intent.
The original issue was the compiler's complaint *that `interval` was not defined*. So what is needed is a value that:

- can be **defined first** and
- **resolved** (delivered) **later**

That sounds like a `promise` to me. As of ClojureScript 1.8.34 Clojure [promise](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/promise)s aren't supported *yet*. Because of the existence of [core.async](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/) there are indications that [support of Clojure's promise isn't an urgent priority in ClojureScript](http://swannodette.github.io/2013/08/23/make-no-promises/) - especially as core.async contains [`promise-chan`](https://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/promise-chan). With `promise-chan` the code could be written as follows

```
(ns test.core
  (:require-macros [cljs.core.async.macros :refer [go]])
  (:require [cljs.core.async :refer [<! close! promise-chan put!]]))

(let [interval (promise-chan)
      fooWin (.open js/window "./foo.html", "windowName")
      checkOnFooWin 
        (fn []
          (when (.-closed fooWin) ;; when has an implicit do
            (go
              (.clearInterval js/window (<! interval)))
            (.alert js/window "Closed")))]
  (put! interval (.setInterval js/window checkOnFooWin 500))
  (close! interval))
```

This code is neither easier nor more elegant than the `atom` version - however it does have the advantage that

- `interval` can only be resolved once
- each and every value taken from `interval` will always be the initially delivered value.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use direct js interop:

```
(let [popup (.open js/window "foo.html" "windowName")]
  (js* "var interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (popup.closed) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            alert('close');
          }
        }, 500);")

    ...)
```